# How to develop Magento 2 Catalog Price Rule programmatically

Tags: magento, module, magento-2.0

I want to develop custom product relater module and for that i have to load catalog price rule conditions . I already added tabular format for my module. Any one can please help me for above problem ?

CRITICAL: Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to abc\ProductFeed\Block\Adminhtml\Productfeed\Edit\Tab\Conditions::setConditionFormName() must be an instance of Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition, null given, called in /var/www/html/mage2016/app/code/abc/ProductFeed/Block/Adminhtml/Productfeed/Edit/Tab/Conditions.php on line 153 and defined in /var/www/html/mage2016/app/code/abc/ProductFeed/Block/Adminhtml/Productfeed/Edit/Tab/Conditions.php

Answer (score 0):

If this is a new module, it is likely you have to run the dependency injection compilation.

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

The error message refers to "arguments." Look at your module's constructor. You will see the relationship between the classes in the error message and the classes you are injecting.

After di:compile and after page refresh, the error should be resolved.